# ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'win32com' Python 3.10

Tags: python, winapi

I am running Python 3.10 and after pip install pywin32 and also pypiwin32, I still get the error of no module named win32com. I have tried everything offered on the older post on here and other sites and still cannot solve the issue.

Please can someone help?

Comment: Check if pip is based on same Python `--version` as Python itself.

Comment: I'm running Python 3.10 on Pycharm and the Pip version is 22.2.2. The rest are:
altgraph = 0.17.2, certifi = 2022.9.24, distlib = 0.3.6, et-xmlfile = 1.1.0, filelock = 3.8.0   
future = 0.18.2, numpy = 1.23.1, openpyxl = 3.0.10, pefile = 2022.5.30,              pipenv = 2022.9.24, platformdirs = 2.5.2, pygame = 2.1.2, pyinstaller = 5.1
pyinstaller-hooks-contrib = 2022.6, pypiwin32 = 223, pywin32 = 304
setuptools = 65.4.1, virtualenv = 20.16.5, virtualenv-clone = 0.5.7
wheel = 0.37.1

Answer (score -1):

https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=_aejASTTVno

Here's the answer. You need to copy the path where pywin32 is installed to "path" (as shown in the video).
You can see where it is installed in the cmd.exe by typing "python -m pip show pywin32". Then create a new file in Pycharm, if you work in it, and write "import pywin32" there. It worked for me.

Comment: Unfortunately this wasnt the answer for me. Ive copied pywin32 to PATH and also copied the scripts path to PATH. I have even copied the win32com path to PATH and I'm still getting No Module named win32com

Comment: There appears on the GitHub page relating to this that there may be an issue with win32com and Python 3.10. If that’s the case, is there an alternative way to export excel to pdf?